# Finding javascript code which is changing style attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly complex Joomla build, the layout of which has become a bit messed up and I'm trying to figure out why.

The style attribute of an element is being changed by javascript (min-height is being added to one element and width to another).

This might be a long shot but is there any way to find out which piece of code is causing this to happen?

Comment: hopefully there is a better way, but couldn't you search your JS for `style.minHeight` and add a unique log (including function name and impacted element) to each time it's found...then watch your log as the page loads and you'll be able to see which function is touching your element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome:

1. open the page
2. open the console (ctrl + shift + j on windows)
3. find the element
4. right-click » Break on... » Attributes modifications
5. reload the page
6. hope the best ;)

Comment: @Mr_Chimp Happy to hear! ;)